# How to pass data continously to next activity after cliking button one time

Tags: android

I am developing android application, I need to pass data continuously to next activity after i click button one time For Ex: i am fetching latitude and longitude from url and sent to next page by using button

```
//This is my url
private static String url = "http://example.com/android/gps/latlong.php";

//i am getting latitude and longitude from url and store into one string

final String latitudee = c.getString("latitude");
final String longitudee = c.getString("longitude");

//Now i need to pass these two values to next page when i click button

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, Nextpage.class);
             intent.putExtra("lat", latitudee);
             intent.putExtra("long",longitudee);
    } 
});


//Next page i am getting those values from mainactivity page

latitudee = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
longitudee = getIntent().getExtras().getString("long");
```

My Requirement:-

Latitude and longitude is coming continuously from url, so i need to pass latitude,longitude to next page continuously after i click one time.

if i click one time and enter into second page, first time data will passing to next page while clicking but i need to get continuous values from main   activity

could you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Use a background service.

Comment: Are you using latitude and longitude in mainactivity?

Comment: @BidhanA could you please give me any sample

Comment: @Nag No i am getting lat,long from url in mainactivity and i need to send lat,long to next page continuously  after i enter into second page by using button

Comment: Two activities do not exist simultaneously (this is how android works), when you call startActivity(..) the calling activity will be paused and stopped while the other runs. This is the reason people are saying you need to handle the data in a background service.

Comment: @stealthcopter  if i use bacground service, i can pass data continuously to next activity?

Comment: Yes. In this instance you'd want a background service that is getting the lat/lng and sending the information on via a broadcast intent. The broadcast intent is a way of passing data to anything that is registered to listen for it.

Comment: @stealthcopte could you please give some sample according to my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

So to do this you need to create a background service that continually checks for the lat and long. Then, each time these values are updated, you would use a broadcast receiver to notify your current activity of the updated values.

Information on how to create a background service can be found here https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html.

Comment: could you please give some sample according to my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code ...  as u `havent` started activity using intent ... use this code ....

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, Nextpage.class);
             intent.putExtra("lat", latitudee);
             intent.putExtra("long",longitudee);
                startActivity(intent);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**In your current Activity, create a new Intent:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

**Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Comment: This will not continually give the updated lat and long. This will only pass it the first time.